# Applying Extrude operation on an instanciated mesh

Tags: modeling, duplicate

I'm currently working on a plan of my house. I'm modelling it using the top view : I created a mesh with only vertices which will be my wall base. Once I'm happy with it, I just take all the vertices then extrude them along the Z axis to give them a height, hence raising the walls. I then apply a solidiy modifier to give them thickness. It works great.

That's nice, but I'm looking for a more "real time" feeling : everytime I want to modify a wall or add a new one, I need have to hide the modifier, delete the upper vertices, make my changes, then extrude back and reapply show the modifier again.

So I thought about the instance option : if I take my base (plane) mesh M1, ALT+D it to a new mesh M2, then apply a solidify modifier to M2, all the changes I make on M1 are reflected on M2. But it lacks the Extrude operation, so M2 is just flat.

So : is it possible to apply an Extrude operation only on an instance's vertex ?